# How to Sort the categories alphabetically?

Tags: sort

[image]

How to Sort the categories alphabetically?

Comment: please try my answer's code once.

Comment: Yes its working Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try below code**

***Using Construct Method***

```
protected $_categoryCollectionFactory;

public function __construct(
    ...

    \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Category\CollectionFactory $categoryCollectionFactory,

    ...
) {
    ...

    $this->_categoryCollectionFactory = $categoryCollectionFactory;

    ...
}

public function getCategoryCollection() {
    $collection = $this->_categoryCollectionFactory->create();
    $collection->addAttributeToSelect('*')->addAttributeToSort('name','ASC');

    foreach ($collection as $category) {
        echo $category->getId() . '<br />';
        echo $category->getName() . '<br />';
        echo $category->getUrl() . '<br />';
    }

}
```

***Using Object manager***

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();

// get the list of all categories
$categoryCollection = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Category\CollectionFactory');
$categories = $categoryCollection->create();
$categories->addAttributeToSelect('*')->addAttributeToSort('name','ASC');

foreach ($categories as $category) {
    echo $category->getId() . '<br />';
    echo $category->getName() . '<br />';
    echo $category->getUrl() . '<br />';
}
```

**I hope it will work...!!!**

Comment: yes its working for me Thanks :)

Comment: ***Please avoid  direct use on object manager***

Comment: i want to Sort the categories alphabetically except last one how it will do?

Comment: last will be at same position.

Comment: @JunaidAshfaq : if you find my answer is useful to you then please upvote the answer so it will help others people as well. Thanks :)

Comment: @AmitBera : now i have updated my answer. if you find my answer is useful to you then please upvote the answer so it will help others people as well. Thanks for the suggestions. Happy Coding :)